# How to ignore camera collision when colliding with the back face of a triangle?

Tags: c#, directx, collision-detection

I was wondering if someone could enlighten me as to how I can ignore camera collision when a camera is colliding with the back face of a triangle. I want to implement this so that my camera cannot get stuck if I, or the player, somehow finds themselves within a model. Here is a video of my camera system:

[A Video My Camera System](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NS7er7a7jvA&feature=youtu.be)

And here is the code for that collision detection:

```
private void CheckKeyboardInput(float deltaTime)
        {
            Vector3 previousCameraLocation = Camera.Location;
            KeyboardState state = Keyboard.GetCurrentState();
            Camera.IsAccelerating = state.IsPressed(Key.LeftShift);
            bool isCameraMoving = false;
            if (state.IsPressed(Key.W))
            {
                Camera.TranslateForward(deltaTime);
                isCameraMoving = true;
            }
            if (state.IsPressed(Key.S))
            {
                Camera.TranslateBackward(deltaTime);
                isCameraMoving = true;
            }
            if (state.IsPressed(Key.A))
            {
                Camera.TranslateLeft(deltaTime);
                isCameraMoving = true;
            }
            if (state.IsPressed(Key.D))
            {
                Camera.TranslateRight(deltaTime);
                isCameraMoving = true;
            }
            if (state.IsPressed(Key.E))
            {
                Camera.TranslateUp(deltaTime);
                isCameraMoving = true;
            }
            if (state.IsPressed(Key.Q))
            {
                Camera.TranslateDown(deltaTime);
                isCameraMoving = true;
            }
            /**
             * Process Camera Collisions
             */
            if (Camera.IsCollisionEnabled)
            {
                if (isCameraMoving)
                {
                    Vector3 currentCameraLocation = this.Camera.Location;
                    int totalCollisions = 0;
                    float finalCameraLocationX = Camera.Location.X;
                    float finalCameraLocationY = Camera.Location.Y;
                    float finalCameraLocationZ = Camera.Location.Z;
                    foreach (StaticGeometry geometry in this.StaticGeometry)
                    {
                        if (geometry.IsCameraCollidable)
                        {
                            if (Vector3.Distance(geometry.Location, Camera.Location) <= Camera.CollisionDistance)
                            {
                                for (int i = 0; i < geometry.Mesh.Vertices.Length; i += 3)
                                {
                                    // Get the Vertex Positions for the current Triangle
                                    Vector3 position1 = geometry.Mesh.Vertices[i].Location;
                                    Vector3 position2 = geometry.Mesh.Vertices[i + 1].Location;
                                    Vector3 position3 = geometry.Mesh.Vertices[i + 2].Location;

                                    // Create the rotation matrix using the geometry's current rotation setting.
                                    Matrix rotationMatrix = VoidwalkerMath.CreateRotationMatrix(geometry.Rotation);

                                    // Transform the Coordinate with the Rotation Matrix, then add the geometry's location
                                    Vector3 finalVertexLocation1 = Vector3.TransformCoordinate(position1, rotationMatrix) + geometry.Location;
                                    Vector3 finalVertexLocation2 = Vector3.TransformCoordinate(position2, rotationMatrix) + geometry.Location;
                                    Vector3 finalVertexLocation3 = Vector3.TransformCoordinate(position3, rotationMatrix) + geometry.Location;

                                    Vector3 translationX = new Vector3(currentCameraLocation.X, previousCameraLocation.Y, previousCameraLocation.Z);
                                    Vector3 translationY = new Vector3(previousCameraLocation.X, currentCameraLocation.Y, previousCameraLocation.Z);
                                    Vector3 translationZ = new Vector3(previousCameraLocation.X, previousCameraLocation.Y, currentCameraLocation.Z);
                                    // Test X
                                    BoundingSphere sphereX = new BoundingSphere(translationX, Camera.HardBoundsRadius);
                                    if (sphereX.Intersects(ref finalVertexLocation1, ref finalVertexLocation2, ref finalVertexLocation3))
                                    {
                                        finalCameraLocationX = previousCameraLocation.X;
                                        totalCollisions++;
                                    }
                                    // Test Y
                                    BoundingSphere sphereY = new BoundingSphere(translationY, Camera.HardBoundsRadius);
                                    if (sphereY.Intersects(ref finalVertexLocation1, ref finalVertexLocation2, ref finalVertexLocation3))
                                    {
                                        finalCameraLocationY = previousCameraLocation.Y;
                                        totalCollisions++;
                                    }
                                    // Test Z
                                    BoundingSphere sphereZ = new BoundingSphere(translationZ, Camera.HardBoundsRadius);
                                    if (sphereZ.Intersects(ref finalVertexLocation1, ref finalVertexLocation2, ref finalVertexLocation3))
                                    {
                                        finalCameraLocationZ = previousCameraLocation.Z;
                                        totalCollisions++;
                                    }

                                    /**
                                     * Edge case early termination. If the camera is already colliding
                                     * on all axis, we don't need to test for any further collisions. This seems
                                     * to only trigger when the player is wedged in a corner.
                                     */
                                    if (totalCollisions > 0) // Might not need this.
                                    {
                                        if (
                                            finalCameraLocationX == previousCameraLocation.X &&
                                            finalCameraLocationY == previousCameraLocation.Y &&
                                            finalCameraLocationZ == previousCameraLocation.Z)
                                        {
                                            this.Camera.Location = new Vector3(
                                                finalCameraLocationX,
                                                finalCameraLocationY,
                                                finalCameraLocationZ);
                                            return;
                                        }
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    this.Camera.Location = new Vector3(finalCameraLocationX, finalCameraLocationY, finalCameraLocationZ);
                }
            }
        }
```

Also my Vertex class, just to show you guys how I have it set up:

```
using SharpDX;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace VoidwalkerEngine.Framework.DirectX.Rendering
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct Vertex
    {

        public static Vertex Zero = new Vertex(Vector3.Zero,Vector2.Zero,Vector3.Zero);

        public Vector3 Location;
        public Vector2 TexCoords;
        public Vector3 Normal;

        public const int Size = 32;


        public Vertex(Vector3 position, Vector2 texCoords, Vector3 normal)
        {
            this.Location = position;
            this.Normal = normal;
            this.TexCoords = texCoords;
        }

        public Vertex(Vertex other)
        {
            this.Location = other.Location;
            this.Normal = other.Normal;
            this.TexCoords = other.TexCoords;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return
                "Location: " + Location.ToString() +
                ", TexCoords: " + TexCoords.ToString() +
                ", Normal: " + Normal.ToString();
        }

    }
}
```

Updated: Camera Class

```
using SharpDX;
using System;

namespace VoidwalkerEngine.Framework.DirectX
{
    public enum CameraMode
    {
        FreeLook,
        Orbit
    }

    public class Camera
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The name of this camera
        /// </summary>
        public string Name { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// The eye location of this camera
        /// </summary>
        public Vector3 Location { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// The Pitch of this Camera, as Radians
        /// </summary>
        public float Pitch { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// The Yaw of this Camera, as Radians
        /// </summary>
        public float Yaw { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// The Roll of this Camera, as Radians
        /// </summary>
        public float Roll { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// The NearZ of this Camera
        /// </summary>
        public float NearZ { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// The FarZ of this Camera
        /// </summary>
        public float FarZ { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// The Field of View of this Camera, value should be
        /// between 0.70 and 1.20
        /// </summary>
        public float FieldOfView { get; set; }
        public float AspectRatio { get; set; }
        public float LookSpeed { get; set; }
        public float MoveSpeed { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Determines if this Camera is currently accelerating.
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsAccelerating { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// The acceleration speed multiplier of this Camera.
        /// </summary>
        public float AccelerationMultiplier { get; set; }
        public CameraMode Mode { get; set; }
        public float ViewportWidth;
        public float ViewportHeight;
        public float HardBoundsRadius { get; set; } = 2.0f;
        public float CollisionDistance { get; set; } = 128;
        public bool IsCollisionEnabled { get; set; } = true;

        /// <summary>
        /// The BoundingSphere of this Camera
        /// </summary>
        public BoundingSphere HardBounds
        {
            get
            {
                return new BoundingSphere()
                {
                    Center = this.Location,
                    Radius = HardBoundsRadius
                };
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The Target Vector of this Camera
        /// </summary>
        public Vector3 Target
        {
            get
            {
                return new Vector3(
                    (float)Math.Sin(this.Yaw),
                    (float)Math.Tan(this.Pitch),
                    (float)Math.Cos(this.Yaw));
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The Frustum of this Camera
        /// </summary>
        public BoundingFrustum Frustum
        {
            get
            {
                return new BoundingFrustum(this.ModelViewProjectionMatrix);
            }
        }

        public Matrix ModelViewMatrix
        {
            get
            {
                return Matrix.LookAtLH(this.Location, Location + Target, Up);
            }
        }

        public Matrix ProjectionMatrix
        {
            get
            {
                return Matrix.PerspectiveFovRH(FieldOfView, AspectRatio, NearZ, FarZ);
            }
        }

        public Matrix ModelViewProjectionMatrix
        {
            get
            {
                return ModelViewMatrix * ProjectionMatrix;
            }
        }

        //public CardinalDirectionType Direction
        //{
        //    get
        //    {
        //        return VoidwalkerMath.GetCardinalDirection(VoidwalkerMath.ToDegrees(Yaw));
        //    }
        //}

        public Vector3 Forward
        {
            get
            {
                return new Vector3((float)Math.Cos(Pitch), 0, (float)Math.Sin(Pitch));
            }
        }

        public Vector3 Right
        {
            get
            {
                return new Vector3(Forward.Z, 0, -Forward.Z);
            }
        }

        public Vector3 Up
        {
            get
            {
                return new Vector3(-(float)Math.Sin(Roll), (float)Math.Cos(Roll), 0);
            }
        }

        public Camera()
        {

        }

        public Camera(string name)
            : this()
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Location = new Vector3();
        }

        public void ToOrigin()
        {
            Transform(Vector3.Zero, 0, 0, 0);
        }

        public void Transform(Vector3 location, float pitch, float yaw, float roll)
        {
            this.Location = location;
            this.Pitch = pitch;
            this.Yaw = yaw;
            this.Roll = roll;
        }

        public float GetCurrentMoveSpeed()
        {
            if (IsAccelerating)
            {
                return this.MoveSpeed * this.AccelerationMultiplier;
            }
            return this.MoveSpeed;
        }

        public void TranslateLeft(float deltaTime)
        {
            float moveSpeed = GetCurrentMoveSpeed();
            this.Location = new Vector3(
                Location.X - (float)Math.Sin(Yaw + MathUtil.PiOverTwo) * moveSpeed * deltaTime,
                Location.Y,
                Location.Z - (float)Math.Cos(Yaw + MathUtil.PiOverTwo) * moveSpeed * deltaTime);
        }

        public void TranslateRight(float deltaTime)
        {
            float moveSpeed = GetCurrentMoveSpeed();
            this.Location = new Vector3(
                Location.X + (float)Math.Sin(Yaw + MathUtil.PiOverTwo) * moveSpeed * deltaTime,
                Location.Y,
                Location.Z + (float)Math.Cos(Yaw + MathUtil.PiOverTwo) * moveSpeed * deltaTime);
        }

        public void TranslateForward(float deltaTime)
        {
            float degreesX = MathUtil.RadiansToDegrees(Pitch) * 0.01745329F; // X rotation
            float degreesY = MathUtil.RadiansToDegrees(Yaw) * 0.01745329F; // Y rotation
            float moveSpeed = GetCurrentMoveSpeed();
            this.Location = new Vector3(
                this.Location.X - (float)(moveSpeed * Math.Sin(degreesY) * Math.Cos(degreesX)) * deltaTime,
                this.Location.Y - (float)(moveSpeed * Math.Sin(degreesX)) * deltaTime,
                this.Location.Z - (float)(moveSpeed * Math.Cos(degreesY) * Math.Cos(degreesX)) * deltaTime);
        }

        public void TranslateBackward(float deltaTime)
        {

            float degreesX = MathUtil.RadiansToDegrees(Pitch) * 0.01745329F; // X rotation
            float degreesY = MathUtil.RadiansToDegrees(Yaw) * 0.01745329F; // Y rotation
            float moveSpeed = GetCurrentMoveSpeed();
            this.Location = new Vector3(
                this.Location.X + (float)(moveSpeed * Math.Sin(degreesY) * Math.Cos(degreesX)) * deltaTime,
                this.Location.Y + (float)(moveSpeed * Math.Sin(degreesX)) * deltaTime,
                this.Location.Z + (float)(moveSpeed * Math.Cos(degreesY) * Math.Cos(degreesX)) * deltaTime);
        }

        public void TransformYawPitch(float dx, float dy)
        {
            Yaw -= dx * LookSpeed;
            Pitch += dy * LookSpeed;
            const float pitchClamp = 1.56f;
            if (Pitch <= -pitchClamp)
            {
                Pitch = -pitchClamp;
            }
            if (Pitch >= pitchClamp)
            {
                Pitch = pitchClamp;
            }
        }

        public void TranslateUp(float deltaTime)
        {
            this.Location = new Vector3(
                this.Location.X,
                this.Location.Y + GetCurrentMoveSpeed() * deltaTime,
                this.Location.Z);
        }

        public void TranslateDown(float deltaTime)
        {
            this.Location = new Vector3(
                this.Location.X,
                this.Location.Y - GetCurrentMoveSpeed() * deltaTime,
                this.Location.Z);
        }

        public void LookAt(Vector3 location, float pitch, float yaw, float roll)
        {
            this.Location = location;
            this.Pitch = pitch;
            this.Yaw = yaw;
            this.Roll = roll;
        }

        public void SetAspectRatio(int width, int height)
        {
            this.ViewportWidth = width;
            this.ViewportHeight = height;
            this.AspectRatio = width / (float)height;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm already aware that I will need to compare the normal of the triangle, in some form or another. I just don't know how to go about this. If someone knows the answer, I would appreciate it. If any other code is needed, just let me know. Thanks!

Comment: If the camera is moving it has a velocity vector. So if  `dotProduct (cameraVelocity, triangleNormal)>0`  you hit the back face of that triangle.

Comment: @Pluto I'm trying to prototype this right now. I'm having some mixed results thus far. I'll let you know.

Comment: @Krythic `cameraVelocity` is just `currentCameraLocation - previousCameraLocation`. You might want to try calculating the triangle normal with the cross product: `triangleNormal = crossProduct(finalVertexLocation2 - finalVertexLocation1, finalVertexLocation3 - finalVertexLocation1)` . This might be flipped depending on triangle winding, if that's the case just swap the arguments.

Comment: @Pluto Wow, that's sounds so much easier than what I just did...which actually sort of worked. Might end up being the same math, but I just saved the result of each movement  into a Vector3 and it appears to be working. I ended up inverting my camera on accident, but it works. Give me a few minutes. And if you wanted to add an answer I'll accept it. ( Going to rewrite this to just do the current - previous instead). Way easier!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the velocity of the camera with `currentCameraLocation - previousCameraLocation` and with a simple dot product find out if you hit the back face of a triangle or not:

```
var cameraVelocity = currentCameraLocation - previousCameraLocation;
bool hitBackFace = Vector3.Dot(cameraVelocity, triangleNormal) > 0;
```

You might want to calculate the triangle normal with the cross product:

```
var triangleNormal = Vector3.Cross(finalVertexLocation2 - finalVertexLocation1, 
                                   finalVertexLocation3 - finalVertexLocation1);
```

The reason for this is that the vertex normals are not *necessarily* the same as the triangle normal. If you think of a triangle on a phong shaded sphere, each of the 3 vertices of that triangle will have a different normal vector, and none of them will be the same as the triangle normal.

Comment: Here's a video of it working if anyone is interested: https://youtu.be/VwzIcXDJWRE

Comment: Slight update. Turns out I did indeed need to get the cross product as you demonstrated in a previous comment. Everything appeared to be working, except for an edge case I noticed where I would erroneously phase through a very specific piece of geometry. After getting the normal via a cross product, the edge case appears to have disappeared. Might want to update your answer to reflect using a Vector3.Cross() computation to calculate a normal. Just doing a dot product is not entirely correct. I'll do more stress testing to see if the issue persists, but I think it's gone.

Comment: Wanted to give one last update and say that ever since i updated my code to use a cross product to get the normal, i have yet to reproduce the phasing bug on the geometry. Going back to my old code, and the problems exists. Therefore i conclude that you must calculate a normal using a cross product. It appears to correct a strange edge case, which to the best of my understanding, happens with steep angles into specfically rotated geometry; something is erroneously calculated. A cross product patches this completely.